# Flash refusing to render on Ubuntu despite a successful install

Tags: 11.10, firefox, flash, google-chrome

Been banging my head against the wall and god knows what. Would appreciate some help on this one.

I have Ubuntu 11.10, 64bit installed with Firefox 9.0.1 and Google Chrome 16.0.912.75.

Flash was installed via Flash-Aid (Firefox extension) earlier and was working fine. About 7 hours back, I hit a bug on one of my programs and wanted to check whether it was a player issue. I decided to switch to a stable release via Flash-Aid. For some reason, the switch didn't work, so I tried to revert back to the beta release once again. No luck either.

The funny thing is both Firefox and Chrome report that the flash player is installed.

### Google Chrome Plugin Tab

> Flash - Version: 11.2 r202
>
> Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202
>
> Name: Shockwave Flash
>
> Version: 11.2 r202
>
> Location: /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so
>
> Disable
>
> MIME types:
>
> MIME type Description File extensions
>
> application/x-shockwave-flash Shockwave Flash
>
> .swf
>
> application/futuresplash FutureSplash Player
>
> .spl

### Firefox Plugin Tab

> Shockwave Flash
>
> Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202

### Location of libflashplayer.so

```
$ locate libflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/libflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so

$ ls -altr /usr/lib/firefox-
addons/plugins/libflashplayer.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 2012-01-23 19:43 /usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/libflashplayer.so -> /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so

$ ls -altr 
/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19M 2011-12-17 20:32 /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so

$ ldd 
/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so
linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007fffe2dff000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f7756633000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f77562fb000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f77560e7000)
libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0x00007f7755e82000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f7755c7a000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f7755a6f000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f7755864000)
libssl3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl3.so (0x00007f775562a000)
libsmime3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmime3.so (0x00007f77553fd000)
libnss3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so (0x00007f77550c5000)
libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so (0x00007f7754ea6000)
libplds4.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplds4.so (0x00007f7754ca1000)
libplc4.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplc4.so (0x00007f7754a9c000)
libnspr4.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnspr4.so (0x00007f7754861000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7754643000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f775443f000)
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f7753e03000)
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f7753b50000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f775392e000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f7753703000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f77534e3000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f77532d6000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f7753018000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f7752dcd000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f7752b35000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f77528ff000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f77526ad000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f77524a9000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f77521b3000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7751f2e000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7751b8f000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7757dba000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f7751973000)
libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f775176a000)
libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f7751550000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f775134a000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f7751131000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f7750def000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f7750beb000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f77509db000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f77507d2000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f77505ce000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f77503cb000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f7750156000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f774ff2f000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f774fd2c000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f774fb22000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f774f8f8000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f774f6ef000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f774f4b3000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f774f2b0000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f774f0a9000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f774eea4000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f774ec86000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f774ea6a000)
```

Everything seems to be in order, but i am obviously missing something. I keep getting
a "Missing Plug-In" message in Chrome and a blank page in Firefox. Firebug inspect confirms that there is no embed in the DOM. Have also checked with Youtube and Metacafe but no luck.

Tried 'sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer' but it didn't work as well (probably since i am on 64bit) with :

```
Setting up flashplugin-installer (11.1.102.55ubuntu0.11.10.1) ...
nspluginwrapper: no appropriate viewer found for /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer /libflashplayer.so
dpkg: error processing flashplugin-installer (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
flashplugin-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem a couple of days ago. I solved it by deleting libflashplayer.so from /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins and recopying it from the folder where I had extracted it from the download. I have no idea why this worked, but it did.